# facebook: what is the use of sharing custom data in facebook pixel

Tags: facebook, advertising

"Audience building can be enhanced by the passing of customData into the track and trackCustom calls. You can not track or optimize for conversions based on custom events at the current time." I read this [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/pixel-events/v2.11).

I was just wondering what would be the benefit of sharing "custom parameters" to facebook? What is audience building here? And how would facebook utilize all these customData?

[image]